# How to validate data in generated swagger c# client before sending

Tags: c#, json, yaml, restsharp

I have a generated c# client generated by swagger editor (yaml file).
I can use the generated funktions to send data and I will get an Exception if I call a constuctor when a needed attribute is null. That is good.

What I´m missing is the data validation that is normally defined in a schema like min length and maximum length.

I tried to create schemas out of the yaml using this Tool [yaml-to-json-schema-generator](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-schema-generator) but generation did not work for me.

Is there any other way of checking values against the yaml definition before sending?
I use Rest Sharp 105.1.0.0 and Newtonsoft Json

Thx in advance